# "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error in program

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am inserting values into a database but get a "column count doesnt match value count value at row1" error.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
    String sql = "insert into login(username,password) values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);

    int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
    out.println(" Data has been submitted ");

    pst.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
} finally {
    try {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ignored) {
        out.println(ignored);
    }
}
```

This my table in MySql database:

```
           +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
           | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
           +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
           | username | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
           | password | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
           +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there something wrong in my code?
Please help me.......

Comment: how much field you have into the login table?

Comment: Can you show us the schema-definition of the table `login`?

Comment: You probably have more fields in your login table.

Comment: @gurung he is already mentioning column names in his query.  "login(username,password)"

Comment: @GPSingh: No he hasn't. I was talking about the table in the database. e.g. if the table has a field called `id` then he might have to do `login(id, username, password) values('', ?, ?)`.

Comment: @gurung how does it matter if he has more fields in his table ? look at his query again.

Comment: One thing he needs to do is update his post with the stacktrace.

Comment: @pratik:i have 2 fields in my login table

Comment: @gurung:i posted my login table aslo...now tell me

Comment: @gurung: if a mandatory column was missing, then the error message would be different

Answer (score 0):

maybe columns are named incorrect in sql String.

Comment: try insert some value (into table login) in mysql command line, check that you have bug in code or in database

Comment: i inserted values into login table in mysql command...values are inserted

Comment: values('?',?) this will insert a ? into username

Comment: @krishnabhargavi comment was meant for skorek

Answer (score 0):

The error is itself erroneous probably, as everything looks fine. Maybe the primary key of the table *login* is not defined (*username*)? I see *username* is nullable.

Comment: I did the same thing as you. And **everything worked**. Difference maybe InnoDB (not ISAM) and using encoding UTF-8 both for DB and driver's connection string. If the encoding given were UTF-16 one could get a nul byte, and that would in a byte encoding be an end-of-string. Bit dubious.

Comment: There are some points where there is a conversion between string and bytes. UTF-16 gives for every char 2 bytes, one of which is for plain ASCII 0. MySQL if thinking the bytes are Latin1 or so, might conceive that as end-of-string. As I said, dubious, far sought.

Comment: First try a non-prepared statement, with String sql = "....'...',...";. I use UTF-8 in my DB, and have a connection string that ends with **&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8**.

Comment: could tell me the syntax how to write

Comment: String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"; and CREATE TABLE `login` (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Can you try the non-prepared statement with a System.out.println(sql)? By the way quotes in the prepared stmt as '?' from another answer is definitely wrong. You do not have a trigger on insert?

Comment: Statement stmt = connection.createStatement... sql = "...'" + username + "'"....; System.out.println(sql); Just being paranoid. Maybe username was null or so.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, a non-prepared statement might give an idea.

```
String sql = "insert into login(username, password) values('"
        + username + "', '" + password + "')";
System.out.println("sql = " + sql);
Statement pst = connection.createStatement();
pst.execute(sql);
```

If nothing helps, create a new table `xxx` and try all on that.

Comment: the method createStatement() in type connection is not applicable for the arguments(string).This error am getting

Comment: With sql = ... on the command line? Maybe there is a trigger on INSERT. Try in MySQL `SHOW TRIGGERS`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this error is caused when the number of values supplied and the number columns does not match.
(i.e)
insert into table (col1,col2) values (val1) 
and 
insert into table (col1) values (val1,val2) 
both would generate same error.

I tried your code and it is perfectly working with Oracle. So, you can check for some spelling mistakes in names of the columns.